# How can I simplify this expression using Collectors.groupingby()?

Tags: java

How can I simplify this expression using Collectors.groupingby()?  Will it be the best solution or are there any better?

```
 public Map<String, List<Account>> findAllAccounts(final List<String> listOfIds) {
        Map<String, List<Account>> result = new HashMap<>();
        listOfIds.forEach(id ->
                result.put(id , getAccount(id)));
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: There is no "best" solution. Because the fastest method may not be the best one in terms of intelligibility. It's just a subjective thing.

Answer (score 2):

*easy-peasy, japanesey!*

```
public Map<String, List<Account>> findAllAccounts(List<String> listOfIds) {
    return listOfIds.stream()
                    .map(this::getAccount)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Account::getId, Collectors.toList()));
}
```

***P.S.** assuming that `getAccount(String id)` is **light** method and not go to DB e.g.*

Comment: unfortunately getAccount does select to database, should I think about another architecture?

Comment: @merc-angel Sure. Only one thing. You should retreive all acounts by given `ids` with **one db request**. After that you can group results into `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` for your case. And with your code, I am guessing `getAccount()` will return `List<Account>`

```
listOfIds.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(id -> id, id -> getAccount(id)));
```